# Using SQLExpression from QueryDsl

Tags: java, sql, querydsl

I want to use the SQLExpressions from QueryDsl. I have a Q-object called qMyClass. Now I want to use the listagg function of the oracle database. Therefore i want to initialize a WithinGroup-object.

```
WithinGroup<Object>.OrderBy withinGroup = SQLExpressions.listagg(qMyClass.attributeName, "/").withinGroup().orderBy(qMyClass.attributeName);
```

The first part

```
SQLExpressions.listagg(qMyClass.attributeName, "/")
```

already gives me the error:

> unknown operation with operator LISTAGG and args
>   [myClass.attributeName, /]

Does anyone know how to use listagg? Didn't find any helpful information on the web. I am using version 4.0.2 of QueryDsl. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select(
    qMyClass.id,
    SQLExpressions.listagg(qMyClass.attributeName,"/")
      .withinGroup()
      .orderBy(qMyClass.attributeName.asc())
      .getValue()
      .as("foo"))
    .from(qMyClass)
    .groupBy(qMyClass.id);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, The orderBy doesn't expect an OrderSpecifier, so I had to remove the `asc()` in your answer. The `getValue().as("foo")` is something I didn't know. I changed my query and now i get the error `No pattern found for LISTAGG`.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: I am using version 4.0.2

Comment: Hi Markus, Do have any suggestion to resolve this "No pattern found" issue

Comment: Hi, I got the same error and couldn't find a solution for it anywhere. My post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65378623/how-to-use-listagg-with-querydsl